# Send email with onclick php

Tags: php

I have a database table when viewed I want to be able to click an icon to send an email to the email address of that table id.
One of the variables is the users email address, and the clicking of the icon or what have you will send the user a notice of completion...with generic message

Here is what I have tried

```
<td align="center">
<a href="#" onClick="emailsend.php?id=<?= $rows['id'] ?>">
<img src="backgrounds/mail.png" border="0">
 </a>
</td>
```

and here is the emailsend.php

```
<?

include "db.inc.php";

$id=$_GET['id'];

$yname=$_POST['yname'];
$yemail=$_POST['yemail'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$reqdoc=$_POST['reqdoc'];
$dept=$_POST['dept'];

// send notice through email


$recipient = $_POST['yemail'];
$subject = "Request";
$forminfo = ($_POST['yname'] . "\n" .
$_POST['yemail'] . "\n" .
$_POST['phone'] . "\n" .
$_POST['reqdoc'] . "\n" .
$_POST['dept'] . "\n" .
 "\n" .
date("d-M-Y  ··  h:i A") . "\r\n\n");

$formsend = mail("$recipient", "$subject", "$forminfo");

?>
```

I know this is completely ugly and likely very wrong, and perhaps there is a better way to do it.
thank you

Comment: And what is the problem? No letter? Do you have a mail service on your pc?

Comment: Your $_POST variables will not get populated this way. They get populated when a form is posted to your server.  Looks like you'll need to do a mysql query.. 'select * from table where id = $_GET['id'].. 
See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php for a full example

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you cant call a php function with an onclick element, you need to use Ajax (XMLHTTPRequest), you can look up here https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/JavaScript/XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Thank you, greatly appreciate your response